# Realm and indexes on properties

Tags: realm

**CONTEXT**

Realm does not support indices on relationship properties (objects). https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#indexed-properties
If you try, it'll throw an error.

We have a situation, where we need to query a model's relationship and another property.

Typically you would do this by having a covering index across (foreign_id, property), but this does not appear to be possible in Realm (yet?)

For example

```
@interface Book : RLMObject
@property NSNumber<RLMInt> * page;
@end

@interface Page : RLMObject
@property Book * book;
@property NSNumber<RLMInt> * line;
@end

[Page objectsInRealm:realm where:@"book.uuid = %@ AND page.line = %@", uuid, @1];
```

**QUESTION**

What is the best way to set up indices so that the query above is optimal?
Are relationships already indexed?
Or Do I create another property on Page, called book_uuid, and index on that?

Cheers

Comment: Well this code should work just fine unless you're trying to call `distinct()` on `book.uuid`.

Comment: But is it indexed? I have hundreds of Books with thousands of pages each.

Comment: In that case I recommend adding a new field in Page and index that

Answer (score 1):

Realm doesn't really cater to the foreign key mechanism of relational databases, so it's easier to get out of that mindset when designing your data model.

In this case, I think it would be more appropriate that your `Book` model stores an array of all of your pages (sort of an inverse to the foreign key concept), which you can use to initially filter the pages to just that book, and to then query for the specific page line:

```
@interface Page : RLMObject
@property NSInteger line;
@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Page)

@interface Book : RLMObject
@property RLMArray<Page *><Page> *pages;
@end

Book *book = [[Book allObjects] firstObject];
Page *page = [[book.pages objectsWhere:@"line = %@", @1] firstObject];
```

As long as you've marked `line` as an indexed property, this should work very quickly in theory. But since you've mentioned you've got thousands of page lines, I'd be curious to see what the real-world performance of this would be.

Comment: Unfortunately, with this approach we cannot directly make use of RLMChangeCollection once the book changes (because we need to make a second query on the book), and also have to briefly block the querying thread. However with some refactoring, and wrapping it in our own "RLMChangeCollection" I think we could make it work.

Comment: The current real-life performance we're seeing, is delays to load the pages of up to 2-3 seconds on an iPad Air, but that's without any indices at all. (We have about 30000 pages in the database as a whole)

Comment: If you're dealing with observing a single `Book`, you can use KVO to observe when its properties are updated. Okay cool! That should hopefully be a lot faster once the pages are indexed.